# PostgreSQL Failure To Reinitialise Replica With pg_basebackup

Tags: postgresql, backup, master-slave-replication, write-ahead-logging

I have a master-replica PostgreSQL 9.5 setup.

I'm trying to reinitialize the replica by doing the following:

- Stop replica service ( `/etc/init.d/postgresql stop` )
- Clear data directory ( `rm -rf /path/to/postgresql/data` )
- Start pg_basebackup ( `sudo pg_basebackup -h master-host -D /path/to/postgresql/data/ --checkpoint=fast -X stream -R -P -v -U replication` )
- Start replica service ( `/etc/init.d/postgresql start` )

Some details:

- It takes the pg_basebackup process to complete around 45mins.
- I'm using `-X stream` to keep up with the changes happening on master while the backup is taking place.
- When the process has finished, the data directory in the replica is ~2GB smaller than the master's (743GB vs 745GB).

When starting the service, these are the output logs:

```
[1869] LOG:  database system is shut down
[2996] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2024-03-18 20:48:03 UTC
[2996] LOG:  entering standby mode
[2996] LOG:  redo starts at 1820/41000098
[2999] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
[2996] LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 1820/4A8CB950
[3001] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 1820/4B000000 on timeline 1
[3004] postgres@template1 FATAL:  the database system is starting up
[3008] postgres@template1 FATAL:  the database system is starting up
```

The service is started but any interaction with it results in the fatal error: `database system is starting up`

Am I missing something in the reinitialisation of the replica? What is causing this behaviour?

Comment: Check this one [Hot Backup Error: the database system is starting up](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/52017/279295)

Comment: `LOG: entering standby mode` means that `standby_mode = on` is specified in `recovery.conf`, but `hot_standby` in postgresql.conf didn't seem to be enabled. In those ancient days of pg9.5, this setting was not enabled by default.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I know, in fact, I am the author of this patch. But the question mentions version 9.5.

Comment: @Melkij thank you for your comment. Quick question: from my understanding the master needs to specify wal_level=hot_standby and the slave needs to have hot_stanbdy=on. Is there a reason why those settings are not on by default? For example how would the replica work if the master specified wal_level=archive?

Comment: To answer this question, I need to write a relatively big historical excursion about the evolution of databases in 2000-2015. Briefly about the reason, “whoever needs it will configure it himself, but everyone who has not changed the configuration will not have to pay for it”. For example wal_level > minimal costs some additional server resources. Now both hot_standby=on and wal_level=replica by default. it's your database stuck in the distant past.

Comment: @Melkij awesome! Thank you so much